# Convergence of slice in an equivalent renorming

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, norms

Let us consider $\ell_2$ space with $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ norm. Let us define a new norm equivalent to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ norm as follows:
$$
\Vert x \Vert_0 = \max \{ \Vert x \Vert_2, \sqrt{2} \Vert x \Vert_\infty \},
$$
where $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ is the supremum norm. Let us denote $X=(\ell_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert_0)$. Then $X$ is a reflexive, non-rotund Banach space that does not have the Kadec-Klee property. Now, I want to check whether "for every $f \in S_{X^*}$ and for every $(x_n) \subseteq B_X$ satisfying $f(x_n) \to 1$,  $d(x_n, S(X, f, 0)) \to 0$ or not". Here
$$S(X, f, 0)= \{ x \in S_X : f(x) \geq 1 \}.
$$
Can anyone help me with this?
I have tried to find an example that does not follow the above criteria, but I am confused whether I am correct or not. So, I have taken $x=\frac{e_1+e_2}{\sqrt{2}}$, $x_n = \frac{e_1+e_n}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $f=(\sqrt{2}, 0, \cdots)$. Then $f(x_n) =1$ and $x \in S(X, f, 0)$; but $\Vert x_n - x \Vert_0 =1$. Could anyone please clarify whether this example is correct or not? Thank you.

One additional question I want to add here: If I slightly change the new norm to $$
\Vert x \Vert_1=\max \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Vert x \Vert_2, \Vert x \Vert_\infty \}.$$
Does $(\ell_2, \Vert \cdot \Vert_1)$ satisfies the above property?